# c++: implement write_padding function

Tags: c++, padding, ofstream

The following question had been asked probably, but I couldn't find it.

I have create a class `BinaryWriter`.
I need to implement the following method:

```
  /// Write zero bytes to file
  virtual void wr_padding( int padding_size);
```

I have the following implementation:

```
void BinaryWriter::wr_padding( int padding_size)
{
  char pad_arr[padding_size];
  memset(pad_arr, 0, padding_size);
  m_stream.write(pad_arr,padding_size);
}
```

where:

```
   std::ostream m_stream;
```

I'm not to happy with this implementation. I was hoping to have an ios API for this simple task. Is there more native implementation?

***Thanks***

Comment: That's not even valid C++...

Comment: what's not valid about it? please elaborate..

Comment: Take a look at this answer (How to write 'n' copies of a character to ostream) : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11421715/808101

Comment: @DannyElly The dimensions of a C style array must be a constant.

Comment: that is correct. but oddly enough, this code compiles and operational.

Comment: You're comment `Write zero bytes...` might easily be misunderstood.

Comment: @DannyElly That's because your compiler has a non-standard language extension

Comment: @jrok so is it a good practice to leave it as is?

Comment: If you're interested in writing portable code, it isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code isn't valid; the size of a C style array must
be a constant.  A valid version would be:

```
void
BinaryWriter::wr_padding( int padding_size)
{
  std::vector<char> pad_arr( padding_size );
  m_stream.write( &pad_arr[0], pad_arr.size() );
}
```

However: can you set some maximum value for `padding_size`?  (In
XDR, for example, it will never be more than 4.)  If so,
something as simple as:

```
void
BinaryWriter::wr_padding( int padding_size )
{
    static char const pad_arr[ max_padding_size ] = {};
    m_stream.write( pad_arr, padding_size );
}
```

would do the trick.

Comment: This is valid C++, if you are not using a old compiler... In C you can do that in c99

Comment: @benjarobin c99 != C++. It's not valid C++, period.

Comment: @benjarobin It is valid C99, but it is _not_ valid C++.

Comment: @jrok You were right, gcc/g++ allow it if -pedantic is not specified: my bad